# Defining an adapter with a static array

Tags: android

I am trying to define and set this adapter in an oncreate method. The stockArray is an ArrayList defined in the main activity (not the same class). I am getting an error which says my constructor is undefined.

```
ArrayAdapter<Object> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(SearchActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MainActivity.stockArray);
```

This is how the array is defined in main activity:

```
public static AsyncTask<ArrayList<Object>, Void, ArrayList<Object>> stockArray;
```

Comment: can you post the code of arrayadapter?

Comment: what is your `MainActivity.stockArray` data type( String? or int? or ?).

Comment: Its an <Object> type.

Comment: post your `MainActivity.stockArray` code

Comment: can you post your error tooltip here ?

Comment: The constructor ArrayAdapter<Object>(SearchActivity, int, AsyncTask<ArrayList<Object>,Void,ArrayList<Object>>) is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting an error because your arrayadapter is of type "`ArrayList<Object>`" and you are passing an instance of type `AsyncTask<ArrayList<Object>, Void, ArrayList<Object>>`

Try passing an instance of type `ArrayList<Object>` to your constructor.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

stockArray in your case is not an array but this

```
AsyncTask<ArrayList<Object>, Void, ArrayList<Object>>
```

In last argument you need to pass an object of type `ArrayList<Object>;`

Answer (score -1):

If your `MainActivity` is an `Activity` object then you can't access an `Array` in that way you have done. You can keep your `Array` as an `static` object in another class , then use in your `Activity` with static access.

```
public class Constants {
    public static final Object [] myArray = { object1 , object2 } ;
}
```

then in your Activity

```
ArrayAdapter<Object> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(SearchActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Constants.myArray);
```

Hope it helps.